# two div vertical align issue

Tags: html, alignment

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

<div></div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

2 div in a row
add unordered list in one of these divs and these 2 divs vertical alignment broken

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `vertical-align: top;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jg3PQ/)

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: top; /* <----- Here */
}
```

I would suggest you to use `float: left;` instead of using `inline-block;` here

[**Float Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jg3PQ/1/) (Don't forget to clear floats)

Comment: thank you for your answer and I'd like to know something under hood. why does the div block move with unordered list inside it?

Comment: You can set a float: left, like example above.

Comment: @LuJun Sorry, didn't got you!

Comment: I mean two div blocks side by side normally before I add the ul tag into one of the div block. How does the ul tag change div block's position?

Comment: @LuJun http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
div{
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}
```